# running subprocess in parallel and getting output

Tags: python-3.x

I'm New here and to coding I am working on a python file to run a program (ATprogram ITs a MCU Program) 3 times at the same but also get the output back from it for later use I have Python running the three programs but how do I get the output from them.

```
import subprocess as s

def progFunction2 (CurrentOS, Programmer, Interface, MCU, Function):

    f_list = ["1", "2", "3"]
    ProgCommand = 'START "programTool" /WAIT "C:/' + CurrentOS + '/Atmel/studio/7.0/atbackend/atprogram.exe" -t ' + Programmer + ' -i ' + Interface + ' -d ' + MCU + ' ' + Function
    #ProgCommand = "cmd"

    procs_list = [s.Popen(ProgCommand, stdout=s.PIPE, stderr=s.PIPE, shell=True) for cmd in f_list]

    for proc in procs_list:
        proc.wait()

presult1 = progFunction2 ("Program Files (x86)","atmelice","ISP","atmega328pb", "chiperase")
```